# Using linear interpolation to fill in gaps in dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to use linear interpolation to fill in the gaps in my data. I'm having trouble with creating a working function and was wondering if I could get some advice.

```
// Desired interpolation temporal resolution in day units.
var tUnit = 'days';
var tResolution = 1;
var year = '2014';

// Create a list of DOYs.
var dateini = ee.Date(year + '-01-01');
var dateend = ee.Date(year + '-12-31');
var nSteps = dateend.difference(dateini, tUnit).divide(tResolution).floor();
var steps = ee.List.sequence(0, nSteps);
var timeRange = steps.map(function(i) {
  return dateini.advance(ee.Number(i).multiply(tResolution), tUnit).millis();
});

var nDays = 31;

// Create a dummy collection with regular time space.
function RegTimeColl(date) {
  var DOY = ee.Date(date).getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);
  var m = ee.Number(ee.Date(date).get('month'));
  return ee.Image.constant(0).rename('EVI')  // Replace 0 with the default value for EVI
      .set({'system:time_start': date, 'DOY': DOY, 'month': m});
}

// Create a dummy collection with regular time space.
var fiveDaysRes = ee.ImageCollection(timeRange.map(RegTimeColl));

// Print the size of fiveDaysRes
print('Size of fiveDaysRes:', fiveDaysRes.size());

// Join Landsat images with the regular time series.
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('LS', 'system:time_start', true, null, true);
var maxMilliDif = (nDays * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * tResolution * 2);
var filter = ee.Filter.maxDifference(
    maxMilliDif, 'system:time_start', null, 'system:time_start');

// Print the result of the join
var joinedCollection = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(fiveDaysRes, harmonicLandsat, filter));
print('Joined Collection:', joinedCollection);

var firstElement = ee.Image(joinedCollection.first());
print('First element in joinedCollection:', firstElement);

// Get DOY of first and last day of the gap-filled reflectance ImageCollection.
var init_doy = ee.Image(harmonicLandsat.first()).get('DOY');
var end_doy =
    ee.Image(harmonicLandsat.sort('system:time_start', false).first()).get('DOY');

// Create an empty list to store the results
var resultList = fiveDaysRes.map(CompositeInterpolate);

// Print the list of results
print('Result List', resultList);

// Function to interpolate values
function CompositeInterpolate(img) {
  var list = ee.List(img.get('LS'));

  // Check if the list exists and has at least two elements
  if (list && list.size().gte(2)) {
    var LSbefore = ee.Image(list.get(0));
    var LSafter = ee.Image(list.get(1));
    var day = ee.Number(img.get('DOY'));
    var ini = ee.Number(LSbefore.get('DOY'));
    var end = ee.Number(LSafter.get('DOY'));
    var tdiff = end.subtract(ini);

    // Check if the time difference is non-zero to avoid division by zero
    if (tdiff.neq(0)) {
      var slope = LSafter.subtract(LSbefore).divide(tdiff);
      var img_inter = LSbefore.add(slope.multiply(day.subtract(ini)));
      img_inter = img_inter.addBands(img_inter.rename('EVI').int16(), null, true); // Rename the band to 'EVI'
      img_inter = img_inter.where(
        day.lte(init_doy),
        harmonicLandsat.filter(ee.Filter.eq('DOY', ee.Number(init_doy))).first()
      );
      img_inter = img_inter.where(
        day.gte(end_doy),
        harmonicLandsat.filter(ee.Filter.eq('DOY', ee.Number(end_doy))).first()
      );
      var time = img.get('system:time_start');
      var month = img.get('month');

      return img_inter.set({
        'day': day,
        'month': month,
        'date_ini': ini,
        'date_end': end,
        'system:time_start': time,
        'year': year
      });
    }
  } else {
    // Handle cases where the list is empty or has only one element
    return img.select('EVI'); // Select the 'EVI' band from the original image
  }
}





// Map the interpolation function over the regular time series.
harmonicLandsat = fiveDaysRes.map(CompositeInterpolate);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your Question to specify the trouble you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix client-side and server-side objects and operations.  Among other things, this will always return true:

```
if (list && list.size().gte(2))
```

Because list (and list.size() and list.size().gte()) are computed objects and they have no actual value until they're evaluated on the server.  Using any of them in a client-side `if` will always evaluate to `true` because they're just Javascript objects and objects always evaluate to true.

In general, you should never reach for a conditional when doing Earth Engine stuff.  Instead, you might filter the collection down to just the ones with a size >= 2 (map over the collection and add the size() as a property), and process those with the interpolation.  Then filter for the other ones, map over those and do the "false" block.  Then merge the results.